# How can I delete a custom class object from a list in python?

Tags: python

I'm really new to python and all I want to be able to do is delete some objects from a list. Basically the list architecture is such: for each list object, there are 5 custom class objects within (?) it, so indexing is like list[0][0], etc. However, I can only wholesale delete something like list[0], taking all the objects with it. This is me just playing around with it in the command line:

```
>>> list.pop()[0][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'nameless_class_to_protect_identity' object does not support indexing
```

So it appears it has something to do with the custom objects themselves. I didn't define this class myself, so I don't really know what's going on. How can I just define something in the class definition so I can delete single objects???

Comment: Uh, you are already deleting it. That's not what the exception is about.

Comment: pop returns the popped element that's why you can't do what you're trying.

Answer (score 2):

What is returned by the pop is an actual element of the list "that does not support indexing" (in short the returned element is not a list (in fact some object can be accessed this way but that's another story)). Hence the exception.

what you can do is:

```
mylist.pop(index) # this will remove the element at index-th position
```

example

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> mylist.pop(1)  # this will remove the element 2 of the list and return it
2  # returned element of the list
>>> print mylist
[1, 3, 4]
```

if your not interested into getting the element removed you can simply use del (given that the index exists):

```
del mylist[index]
```

example

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> del mylist[2]
>>> print mylist
[1, 2, 4]
```

In case of nested lists:

```
>>> mylist = [[1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c'], 5]
>>> mylist[0].pop(1)  # we pop the 2 element (element at index 1) of the list at index 0 of mylist
2
>>> print mylist
[[1], ['a', 'b', 'c'], 5]
>>> mylist.pop(1)[1]  # here we pop (remove) the element at index 1 (which is a list) and get the element 1 of that returned list
'b'
>>> print mylist  # mylist now possess only 2 elements 
[[1], 5]
```

*On an unrelated note I've called the list variable `mylist` instead of `list` in order not to override the `list` built-in type.*

Comment: You should add an example for nested lists as this seems to be his actual use case; e.g. `mylist[0].pop(1)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!!! I knew there had to be an easy solution, but I was having so much trouble finding it.